# Sharepoint 2010. Place a web-part with the list from another site

Tags: 2010, list, web-part

I Need a solution to insert a web-part on the page on one site and the web-part shall contain list from another SP space.

Is there any solution available without SP designer?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "another SP space"? Another site collection? Another farm?

Comment: Another site collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible within the same site collection.
Go to the site that has the list view you want.  Add a content editor webpart with the following:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('div[allowExport="false"]').attr("allowExport","true");
});
</script>
```

Now you can export the webpart you want.

Next, open the .webpart file in notepad and look for

```
<property name="WebId" …>all_zeros_guid_here </property>
```

Replace the zeros with the GUID of the site the list is on.  You can get it by going to _layouts/sitemanager.aspx  When you hover over a site in the right side, the GUID is displayed at the bottom left of the window.  ScreenCapture it and type it in.

Save and upload webpart

Gotchas apply and include:
Only within site collection; Not tested with all list/lib; Will error while you allow editing of content type on target list

Source:http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2009/03/sharepoint-one-library-multiple-sites.html

Otherwise, your only other OOTB option is a page viewer webpart.

Also feel free to Google 3rd party solutions.